# why doesn't this Perl capture work

Tags: regex, perl

I expected this to capture and print just the group defined in parens, but instead it prints the whole line.  How can I capture and print just the group in parens?

```
echo "abcdef" | perl -ne "print $1 if /(cd)/ "
```

What I want this to print: `cd`

What it actually prints: `abcdef`

How to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the perl command, you have to use single quotes or protect variables :

```
echo "abcdef" | perl -ne "print \$1 if /(cd)/"
```

or

```
echo "abcdef" | perl -ne 'print $1 if /(cd)/'
```

In double quotes, the shell expand $1.

Comment: Why did you answer? This is what my answer said already (updated at least three minutes before your answer, and just edited slightly since then).

Comment: You have noise in your response, I'm going to essential. No need the `m` keywork in this context. Moreover, I give examples.

Comment: Haha, I like that "noise." You do have a good point. Sometimes m is needed when changing delimiters, etc., and so that is a more common mistake that I see (but definitely not needed in this case). It's been so long since I made the mistake of using double quotes or not protecting a variable that I looked straight at the -e code and manually typed it into the command line (changing to single quotes without thinking) and adding m/. It wasn't tell I looked back at the question to see whether I mistyped something since I was getting a different result, that I realized there were double quotes.

Comment: Follow up question: what if the pattern I wish to find contains a single quote in it? Ah actually I guess that's where I'd use the first approach of dbl quote + variable protection.  Nice

Comment: In the input, that changes nothing. If it's in the perl code, you should prevent quotes by backslashing.

Answer (score 1):

The instant fix to your question is to change your double quotes to single quotes, like this:

```
       $ echo abcdef | perl -ne 'print $1 if /(cd)/'
       cd
```

With double quotes, the shell environment interprets your unprotected variable $1, which in your environment apparently evaluates to an empty string. So perl only receives the command `print if /(cd)/` which is an implied command `print $_ if /(cd)/` which prints the entire line.

You can also use a protected variable like this:

```
       $ echo abcdef | perl -ne "print \$1 if /(cd)/"
       cd
```

Note that matches which use different delimiters (other than / and /) are required to begin with the `m` keyword rather than using the shorthand form. But in your case, this does not matter, but it is often something worth being aware of when working with matches, e.g., m|/| would match a `/` character using the pipe as the delimiter for the regular expression.